# get list of versions from JIRA REST API

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to retrieve a list of all the possible values of "Affects Version/s" field for a particular project using JIRA REST api.

Similarly for "Component/s" field.

Does such a REST api exist in JIRA?

Comment: Have you looked at the JIRA developer documentation? Do you have any code examples of what you have tried? These are minimum requirements to get your question answered.

Comment: yes i did look into the JIRA rest api documentation. In terms of version the closesnt thing i found was to get details of a particular version when provided with the ID of the version  /rest/api/2/version/{id}.    However I did not find anything which would give me a list of all the possible values for version.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking in the wrong portion of the API documentation.  Have a look at getProjectVersions.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-getProjectVersions

Comment: Or for Jira Cloud there is a similar [api](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-project-versions/#api-rest-api-3-project-projectidorkey-versions-get)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the JIRA API is lacking what would be some very useful capabilities and have had to fill in with custom queries and scripts that enable them.

In your case you may have to query the JIRA database manually with SQL to get the dataset you seek.